# Which Google Cloud Platform service to use to implement a REST API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are just starting a new project using Google Cloud.
We will use:

- Web server
- Compute engine (data processing)
- MySQL

And here is my question: We have developed a REST API to respond web queries to the database. It is now running on flask (python) on the dev CE. 
I don't fully understand which service I need to host the API. 
I assume that it will be cheaper than CE or MySQL but don't know which one it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute Engine would work fine to implement a REST API although depending on your situation there may be better options. However, if you are interested [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-compute-engine-rest) is a tutorial on how to get that setup.

I would suggest you look into [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) and [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/). Both are great options for building a REST API.

Cloud Endpoints is a API management tool that comes with features to help develop, deploy, and manage API's. It runs as a layer infront of on App Engine, Kubernetes, or Compute Engine.

Cloud Functions is an event based serverless architecture. By utilizing Cloud Functions you only pay for the calls you make, can scale seamlessly, and are not required to manage a VM.